# Activi Explorer throwing PartialResultException when we ignore partial and use ldaps (636)

Tags: ldap, activiti, bpmn

We are using secure ldap server with port 636.
When we are using baseDn to root baseDn, it's throwing PartialResultException. We solved the similar issue in grails application by allowing PartialResultException.

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true

Can we also ignore PartialResultException in Activiti-Explorer LDAPUserManager ?

````
        ```
        javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'DC=XX,DC=XXX,DC=com,DC=au'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2914)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:148)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:217)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:189)
        at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPUserManager$3.executeInContext(LDAPUserManager.java:271)
        at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPUserManager$3.executeInContext(LDAPUserManager.java:254)
        at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPTemplate.execute(LDAPTemplate.java:44)
        at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPUserManager.checkPassword(LDAPUserManager.java:254)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CheckPassword.execute(CheckPassword.java:37)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CheckPassword.execute(CheckPassword.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.IdentityServiceImpl.checkPassword(IdentityServiceImpl.java:99)
        at org.activiti.explorer.ui.login.DefaultLoginHandler.authenticate(DefaultLoginHandler.java:43)
        at org.activiti.explorer.ui.login.DefaultLoginHandler.authenticate(DefaultLoginHandler.java:35)
        at org.activiti.explorer.ui.login.LoginPage$ActivitiLoginListener.onLogin(LoginPage.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
        at com.vaadin.ui.LoginForm$2.handleParameters(LoginForm.java:103)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Window.handleParameters(Window.java:515)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:528)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at org.activiti.explorer.filter.ExplorerFilter.doFilter(ExplorerFilter.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:932)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        ```
````

1. We changed the baseDn to the ldap location where all the users are created. This worked but it's a kind of a hardcoding of baseDn. A new user has be be created in the same directory and we don't want that.
2. Use 3269 (global Catalog). But we don't want to expose the port 3269 except 636
3. If these is any possibility to change activiti-custom-context.xml to ignore PartialResultException. Unfortunately we couldn't find any property which can ignore the exception.